# 2 rich edit controls, same text

Tags: c#, .net, string, richtext

I've put 2 rich edit controls, which should display the same text. So, when I edit the text in one of them, the other should reflect the changes.
The problem is - I don't want to put this code in Text Changed event:

```
control1.rftText = control2.rtfText
```

because it will create a new instance of the string each time the text is edited.

Is there any way to send the same instance of the string to the both of the controls or are there any other solutions to the problem?

Comment: Two words: premature optimization. Write the code that makes sense. Don't "fix" it until you notice performance problems.

Comment: Copying strings is not necessarily bad, and copying strings are in general very fast. It is a bad approach in certain scenarios, but I think for this one it will be the best one. Go with the simple solution, and fix it if it becomes a performance hog.

Answer (score 1):

`control1.rftText` is an immutable string so if you want to modify it, you'll have to create a new string.

Using this `control1.rftText = "my new string"` will simply create a new string and appoint it to `rftText` field as you said. If you are really serious about optimizing this sort of value assignments, you can create your own implementation of a derived rich edit class where it will use some sort of a `StringBuilder` logic, or you may internally represent the text as a char[] array and modify that, but they may turn out to be a real challenge, so decide wisely.

Comment: How exactly does this answer the question? You're missing a leap of logic or something.